# How to implement ConfirmDialog

Tags: vaadin

The simple example for the ConfirmDialog shows this:

```
ConfirmDialog dialog = new ConfirmDialog("Meeting starting",
        "Your next meeting starts in 5 minutes", "OK", this::onOK);
Button button = new Button("Open dialog");
button.addClickListener(event -> dialog.open());
add(button, dialog);
```

This assumes some knowledge that I apparently don't possess. Namely, how to implement "this::onOK".  Can anyone give me a quick example of how to create this listener such that when I click the OK button, the dialog just closes?

Comment: The latest component docs contain full source code for all examples (click "Show code" and then the "expand code" icon button"), so you don’t need to guess the hidden parts: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/confirm-dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this::onOK` is a method reference that takes the `ConfirmEvent` as parameter
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

The method to implement looks like this:

```
private void onOK(ConfirmDialog.ConfirmEvent confirmEvent) {
}
```

You could also pass the code directly as a lambda expression:

```
ConfirmDialog dialog = new ConfirmDialog("Meeting starting",
    "Your next meeting starts in 5 minutes", "OK", e -> { // your code });
```

https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_lambda.asp

Answer (score 1):

This should close the dialog when the button is clicked.

```java
        ConfirmDialog dialog = new ConfirmDialog("Meeting starting",
                "Your next meeting starts in 5 minutes", "OK", e -> e.getSource().close());
        Button button = new Button("Open dialog");
        button.addClickListener(event -> dialog.open());
        add(button, dialog);
```

Comment: Not only close but also execute the code that should be run when the user confirms